# Page number appearing on the bibliography item

Tags: bibliographies, citing

when I cite the items on the bibliography, I get the page numbers where citation happen appear after the bibliography. For eg: in the image, the number "3" at the end is the page number where this bib item is cited. I don't want this happening.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{titlepage}

\normalsize
\tableofcontents

\input{Introduction}
\input{SystemDescription}
\input{ControllerDesign}
\input{ObserverDesign}
\input{LinearController}
\input{Comparison}
\input{Conclusion}
\input{Recommendation}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a MWE to your question. Without knowing the code you have used it is nearly impossible to give you an appropriate answer. A helpfull hint may nevertheless be, that this behaviour might occure due to an option or package related to so called backreferencing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP does not provide a compilable MWE, it is difficult to troubleshoot the issue. However, the behaviour of back-referencing is usually related to hyperref package, with the extension option for back-referencing invoked, e.g. `backref=true` and `pagebackref=true`.

Setting such options to `backref=false` and `pagebackref=false` helps disabling back-referencing. For further information, see hyperref manual http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html

Comment: Where am I supposed to look for backref? I don't find it any of the files.

Comment: How am I, then, supposed to know when you do not provide an MWE?

Comment: Look for `\usepackage{hyperref}` `\hypersetup{backref=true, pagebackref=true}` or something like that. It is guessing, again.

Comment: I found it. pagebackref=true was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that it helps.